# Gtx 960 Subvendor ID of 0000

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, bios, nvidia-geforce

A friend bought a new PC with a GTX 960. We installed the newest GeForce drivers and checked the device information with the Windows device manager and a 3rd  program called Speccy

The subvendor id is listed as "0000" undefined for both of them.

Is the card a fake? The 3DMark benchmark seems to match the average GTX 960
I think it might be due to missing updates, old BIOS, faulty card, a bad BIOS configuration, or perhaps there are manufacturers who don't care about this field?

It seems to be this card:
http://www.manli.com/en/products/NVIDIA_Graphics_Cards/9_Series/products/63

We were in a hurry so we couldn't check everything. I will be able to check the system next weekend.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

looks like manli, the manufacturer of this gtx 960 is no member of pcisig, so there is no subvendor id. the card has been tested with multiple games and benchmarks and performs as expected.